# Choose one file that has a specific name and the most recently updated

Tags: r

I want to choose a file like the following line, which didn't do as I wished.

```
which(substr(rownames(fInfo),1,8) == "mySource" ) & which.max(fInfo$mtime)
```

In an English sentence, I want to choose files whose names start with "mySource" and within those whom chosen, I want to pick the most recently updated file.

My script below is suffice, but it is too long. Can someone shorten my script?

```
# create dummy files under Folder "scriptFld"
ifelse(!dir.exists(file.path("scriptFld")), dir.create(file.path("scriptFld")), FALSE)
strTime = format(Sys.time(), "%H%M")
file.create(NA, paste0("scriptFld/mySource1_", strTime,".R")); Sys.sleep(1)
file.create(NA, paste0("scriptFld/mySource2_", strTime,".R")); Sys.sleep(1)
file.create(NA, paste0("scriptFld/notMySource3_", strTime,".R"))


# read source R files
setwd("scriptFld")
fInfo = file.info(list.files()) # find all files under the folder "scriptFld"
iCandidate = which(substr(rownames(fInfo),1,8) == "mySource") # focus on file names starting with "source"
iCandidateMax = iCandidate[ which.max(fInfo$mtime[iCandidate]) ] # choose the most recent file
fSourceName = rownames(fInfo)[iCandidateMax]
source(file = fSourceName) # This is what I want, except the script is too long.
setwd("..")
(fSourceName)
```

Comment: How about `x <- list.files(pattern = "^mySource"); source(x[which.max(file.info(x)$mtime)])` assuming you set the wd correctly before this

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)
files <- list.files("scriptFld", pattern = "^mySource", full.names = TRUE)
files %>%
  file.info() %>%
  pull(mtime) %>%
  which.max() %>%
  files[.] %>%
  source()
```